# Mathematical processing on text file

Tags: statistics, math

I have 200 text files. Each text file contains one column of mathematical numbers (100k rows).

I want to do some statistical processing on these data (finding the probit or quantile). I know the mean and sigma value associated for each file. Is there any direct way to calculate probit or quantile of a dataset?

If not, then I know the formula for quantile which is =(sorted data-mean)/sigma. e.g.

*input_file.txt*

```
12.2  
10.11  
15.55  
5.01  
...
...
12.9
```

*temp.txt*

```
5.01  
10.11  
12.2  
12.9  
15.55  
... 
...
```

Final output file should contain two columns. First column is same as `temp_output.txt` and second column is the following mathematical function on each element:

```
= (row(i)-mean)/sigma
```

Where mean and sigma are two mathematical number say 10.1 and 2.02 respectively. Final output file should look like this for above values

*output.txt*

```
5.01 -2.51980198  
10.11 0.004950495  
12.2 1.03960396  
12.9 1.386138614  
15.55 2.698019802  
... 
...
```

Comment: If someone does you the courtesy of editing your question to make it (a) more readable, and (b) formatted to the U&L style guidelines, please don't roll it back: it is both rude and counter productive.

Comment: Sorry, that was not the intention. I want to edit one word in the question to make it more clear. Thanks for editing and formatting.

Comment: That's cool; it's a wiki, it is suposed to be edited. I just didn't  understand why you completely removed my changes.

Comment: whats your programming lang?

Comment: @jasonwryan This happens with simultaneous edits sometimes.

Comment: I am not restricted to any language for this work. But any command line single liner solution is highly appreciated, as I have to perform the edit on 200 files one by one.

Comment: Nilesh, please install [R](http://cran.r-project.org/), and look over at Stack Overflow for [recipes](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[r]%20probit).

Comment: sorry, where you get the value for mean and sigma ? from input_file.txt ? will file be processed one by one ? e.g. mean1 and sigma1 from file1.txt mean2 and sigma2 from file2.txt and so forth.

Comment: yes, files will be processed one by one with mean1, sigma1 for file1.txt and mean2, sigma2 for file2.txt and so on. The values of mean and sigma is not stored in file it is known to me for each file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

do you meed something like this

```
mybox $ cat file1.txt
12.2
10.11
15.55
5.01
mybox $ awk -v mean=10.2 -v sigma=2.02 '{printf "%f %f\n",$1,($1-mean)/sigma ; }' file1.txt
12.200000 0.990099
10.110000 -0.044554
15.550000 2.648515
5.010000 -2.569307
```

the cryptic part

```
awk -v mean=10.2 -v sigma=2.02 '{printf "%f %f\n",$1,($1-mean)/sigma ; }' file1.txt
```

how do you intend to provide mean1,mean2, ... mean200 ?